# Was Billy in the same room as before?

Tags: goliath

In season 3 of Goliath, Billy ends up getting comped a room at the casino. For some reason, he tears the mirror off the wall in the bathroom and sees a message written on the wall. We later learn that it was he who wrote it while he was blacked out during a previous trip near by.

What I don't understand is when he's being told what happened by Lauren Tom's character, she asks him, "why did you get this room instead of the suite like last time?".

If he was in a different room last time, how was it that he got in and wrote the message in the room he is in now?

Something else: while showing the flash backs of the party in the room where he meets the guy from the state water board, they are in what looks like his current room. Was this a discrepancy in the story?